# pd.to_numeric fails on xarray time coordinate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I've got a new computer and new Python installation, and now the following code does not work any more:

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

tt     = np.arange('2005-02', '2005-03', dtype='datetime64[D]')
data   = np.arange(len(tt))**2
series = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[tt], dims=['time'])

series.plot()    ## just to confirm that *series* is what it should be

pd.to_numeric(series.time)
```

The error output is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_10090/418031900.py in <module>
      9 series.plot()    ## just to confirm that *series* is what it should be
     10 
---> 11 pd.to_numeric(series.time)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    176         pass
    177     elif is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype(values_dtype):
--> 178         values = values.view(np.int64)
    179     else:
    180         values = ensure_object(values)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    237                 with suppress(KeyError):
    238                     return source[name]
--> 239         raise AttributeError(
    240             "{!r} object has no attribute {!r}".format(type(self).__name__, name)
    241         )

AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'view'
```

My old installation simply produced

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 28)>
array([1107216000000000000, 1107302400000000000, 1107388800000000000,
       1107475200000000000, 1107561600000000000, 1107648000000000000,
       1107734400000000000, 1107820800000000000, 1107907200000000000,
       1107993600000000000, 1108080000000000000, 1108166400000000000,
       1108252800000000000, 1108339200000000000, 1108425600000000000,
       1108512000000000000, 1108598400000000000, 1108684800000000000,
       1108771200000000000, 1108857600000000000, 1108944000000000000,
       1109030400000000000, 1109116800000000000, 1109203200000000000,
       1109289600000000000, 1109376000000000000, 1109462400000000000,
       1109548800000000000])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2005-02-01 2005-02-02 ... 2005-02-28
```

If I convert the *values* of series.time and make a new xarray out of them, I get the desired result

```
ttt = pd.to_numeric(series.time.values)
tttt = xr.DataArray(ttt, coords=[tt], dims=['time'])
tttt
```

but I do not think that this work-around is a desirable solution.

It worked well on my old computer and installation (xarray 0.16.2, pandas 1.0.5, numpy 1.19.4). My new installation has xarray 0.18.2, pandas 1.3.0, and numpy 1.20.3.

Any ideas about what's going wrong or how to solve the problem?

Comment: I think your workaround is fine: what do you feel is wrong with it?

Comment: Note that `pd.to_numeric` does not handle an xarray DataArray. It, perhaps accidentally, used to work, but the documentation for `to_numeric` mentions "scalar, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series".

Comment: You could also try with `series.time.to_series()` instead of `.values` (note that `series` as a variable name is a bit of a misnomer, since it is a DataArray).

Comment: This looks like the result of [this recent pull request in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/38840).  I suppose one solution would be to add a `view` method to `xarray.DataArray`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What's wrong with my solution? It's unelegent - xarray in - xarray out intuitively looks kind of natural.

Comment: You could file an issue with `xarray` (if there isn't one already), and downgrade Pandas until this is fixed in `xarray` (if the `xarray` developers agree, of course).

Comment: Another workaround would be to avoid pandas and convert the `datetime64[ns]` values to integers with `astype`, e.g. `series.time.astype(np.int64)`.